# CRC calculation for header CRC and Data block using C# .net API

Tags: header, crc, payload

I am trying to send the customised protocol message as bytes data in my C# application. In my application ,I was asked to do the CRC calculation for the Header Block then do the CRC calculation for the existing CRC( Header block) and Data Block.

So I have two questions to ask related to my issue.

1) why can not we do CRC calculation together as a whole block of Header and Data ?

2) What exiting C# API can be used to calculate the CRC for the header block then do the 2nd CRC for existing one and actual data?

Comment: I assume you can generate CRC for header block, append to the header block, then generate CRC for the combined header block + header crc + data block, and append that after the data block.

Comment: what is the purpose of doing it twice?

Comment: Any other c# API which I use it for?

Comment: `what is the purpose of doing it twice?` - I'm not sure.  If multiple devices are connected to a common bus, then the header CRC may be used to verify the header before responding to the message.